# How to select rows without duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have a query making me scratch my head a bit.

I have a table of transactions. It includes Type, Date, Time, Quantity, etc. There are about 30 types. Unfortunately types 1 and 2 *might* come in pairs, The date, time and quantity let me know if they are indeed the same transaction being duplicated.

Can I get all rows of all types excluding type 1 and 2 where date, time, and quantity match?

example input:

```
Row | Type | Qty | Date                   | Time |
1   |  1   | 12  | 2015-01-06 00:00:00.000| 74501|
2   |  1   | 15  | 2015-02-06 00:00:00.000| 91023|
3   |  2   | 15  | 2015-02-06 00:00:00.000| 91023|
4   |  3   | 7   | 2015-03-10 00:00:00.000|151256|
```

The issue is Rows 2 & 3 represent the same transaction. So my select statement needs to return row 1, 3, 4 (or 1, 2, 4).

Note: Type 2 always has a type 1, type 1 does not always have a type 2.

Please help me phrase this better!

Comment: Please post sample data and desired results, to better explain what you are trying to do.   Though I suspect you can do what you want with a CASE statement, both in the select list and in a GROUP BY.

Comment: is there a way I can add a table?

Comment: You can copy and paste text in any format into your question.   You can use the {} code view button to retain the exact format instead of having all your line breaks ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add more columns after the list in partition by...

```
WITH dups AS 
  (SELECT *, row_number() over 
    (PARTITION by Date, Time, Quantity ORDER BY type) 
   AS c1 FROM t2)

SELECT DISTINCT type, date, time, quantity 
FROM dups 
WHERE c1 > 1 
AND type not in (1,2)
```